# Can Chrome extension content script access all tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Basically, I want to get all the opened tabs of the browser window, from within a tab, more specifically, in **content script**.

I tried [**`chrome.tabs.query`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query), it works in **background script**, but doesn't work in **content script**.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to do such work? Maybe an API that I wasn't aware of?
2. Or, can I dispatch an event from **content script**, then capture the event in **background script**, and vice versa?
3. Or, is it just impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts , a content script cannot access chrome.* APIs, except a few allowed ones but chrome.tabs is not among them

Exchanging messages with the parent script is possible, though, so this might be the way to do it. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging I found this link helpful and it solves my problem. Could you update it to your answer? Thanks.